# windows XP - View history of commands in cmd.exe

Tags: windows, windows-xp, cmd.exe

Is it possible to view the history of commands entered in cmd.exe? And by previous, I mean the commands I entered from yesterday for example.

I created a .bat file. I execute it in cmd.exe along with a keyword(command.bat keyword). I'd like to know that keyword because I can't remember it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Microsoft command history is not maintained across sessions, and is still the case with later OS and Powershell sessions.

For XP during the same session you can use up / down arrows to access current hisory or F7 to view session history commands and F9 to jump to command.

There are third party alternative to the windows command line that offer history across sessions. but that doesn't really help with your yesterday history.